# angularjs 1.5 component databinding to array

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, angular-components

I am not able to figure out the databinding syntax to bind an array to a table. I have a parent TodoComponent which is passing a todoList to a child component TodoListComponent. The child component (TodoListComponent) is receiving the data correctly but is not binding to the template.

The parent component

```
const TodoComponent = {
    bindings: {
        todos: '<'
    },
    template: `
        <div class="todo">
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <todo-list todos="$ctrl.todos"></todo-list>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    `
};
```

The child component

```
const TodoListComponent = {
    bindings: {
        todos: '<',
    },
    template: `
        <tr ng-repeat="todo in $ctrl.todos">
            <td>{{ todo.text }}</td>
        </tr>
    `
};
```

If I just print out the json it displays the data so I know the data is returned

```
template: `
    <pre>{{$ctrl.todos|json}}</pre>
  `
```

Comment: you first template should pass `$ctrl.todoData` like `<todo-list todos="$ctrl.todoData"></todo-list>`

Comment: @PankajParkar I just edited the question to also show my controller. As you can see I am setting todos from todoData. And as I mentioned the data is being passed to the child component. Its the data binding thats not working.

Comment: `this.todos` inside a $onChanges function is not `this.todos` of controller

Comment: As I have already mentioned, I am getting the data $ctrl.todos in the child component and I can print out the data there. Its the databinding thats not working. My questions is regarding the databinding syntax.

Comment: Apologies, could you please create a plunkr/fiddle?

Comment: @PankajParkar no worries. All help is much appreciated. As in my answer below, i've got it working for now.

Comment: What do you mean by you can't have template for table row.. please add your html as well, Thanks

Comment: @PankajParkar I added the relevant html code for parent and child components. Omitted the header info as not relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like I cannot have a child template just for the table row with the table in the parent template. When I moved the entire table to the child template it worked. If anyone else can post an alternative I will be glad to accept that as the valid answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem, and solved with Two-way data binding "=".

Have you tried using it?

```
...
     bindings: {
            todos: '='
        }
...
```

Comment: Sorry I fail to see the relevance to the issue. Why would I need two way binding?